# How to insert integers into an array from same line in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, input

I am using the following code to insert array value from same line of input

```
s = Array.new(10)    
q = gets
s = q.split(' ')
```

It is working fine. but if I don't want to take variable to store at first and split after that but directly take input in the array by using following code I fail.

```
s = Array.new(10)
10.times do
  s.push gets.split.map(&:to_i)
end
```

What is the correct code to take integer inputs from same line? Need help.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the string from the user input always includes exactly ten numbers?

Comment: Your first code does not make sense. You create an array `s`, and are immediately overwriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare the array first. split method returns an array, and you can assign it to the variable. This will do

```
s = gets.split(' ').map &:to_i
```